# How do you use Mongoose without defining a schema?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

In previous versions of Mongoose (for node.js) there was an option to use it without defining a schema

```
var collection = mongoose.noSchema(db, "User");
```

But in the current version the "noSchema" function has been removed. My schemas are likely to change often and really don't fit in with a defined schema so is there a new way to use schema-less models in mongoose?

Comment: just use Mongodb plain, thats schema less by default

Comment: What about collection method of createConnection() instane?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

I think this is what are you looking for [Mongoose Strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)

**option: strict**

The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values added to our model instance that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

**Note: Do not set to false unless you have good reason.**

```
    var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
    var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);
    var thing = new Thing({ iAmNotInTheSchema: true });
    thing.save() // iAmNotInTheSchema is now saved to the db!!
```

Comment: You saved my day. I also found out that this must not be used with #markMotified('<columnName>')

Comment: PS: You have to do `thing.set(key, value)` because `thing.key=value` doesn't work with this method, i.e. it doesn't persist changed into the database otherwise.

Comment: If you use this method, you will run into issues when retrieving the docs. After doing a find and then doc.someProp doc.someProp will be undefined, even though it is actually there on the object (a console.log confirms this), this is because mongoose defines its own getters which seem to only work if you define that prop on the schema

Comment: @a20: I understand what you say about `MySQL` :) And I think [Jonathan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/708618/jonathan-p-diaz) suggestion/as per [Mongoose API Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) __Note: Do not set to false unless you have good reason__. Is absolutely fine with the current context (about only `NO-SQL`)

Comment: @Melbourne2991 this is true to an extent, however there is a workaround that I found. You can call the toJSON() method on the document that you retrieved which will then allow you to use your regular dot notation like doc.someProp. Sorry to reply on such an old answer. Just wanted to add this in case someone comes across the same thing.
[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON)

Comment: @Leandros Whenever I query data using this schema and try to print each element returned it gives undefined.

Comment: If you have already a schema, you can do this: `UserSchema.set('strict', false)`

Comment: Hello it worked with : const schema = new mongoose.Schema({} ,{ strict: false });

Answer (score 68):

Actually "Mixed" (`Schema.Types.Mixed`) mode appears to do exactly that in Mongoose...

it accepts a **schema-less**, **freeform JS object** - so whatever you can throw at it.  It seems you have to trigger saves on that object manually afterwards, but it seems like a fair tradeoff.

> ### Mixed
>
> An "anything goes" SchemaType, its flexibility comes at a trade-off of
>   it being harder to maintain. Mixed is available either through
>   `Schema.Types.Mixed` or by passing an empty object literal. The
>   following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> var Any = new Schema({ any: {} });
> var Any = new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed });
> ```
>
> Since it is a schema-less type, you can change the value to anything
>   else you like, but Mongoose loses the ability to auto detect and save
>   those changes. To "tell" Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has
>   changed, call the `.markModified(path)` method of the document passing
>   the path to the Mixed type you just changed.
>
> ```
> person.anything = { x: [3, 4, { y: "changed" }] };
> person.markModified('anything');
> person.save(); // anything will now get saved
> ```

- [Mongoose Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)

Comment: Is this still the right way to work schema-less with Mongo/Mongoose?

Comment: But this structure nests the entire object under the `any` field, so it does in fact have a schema.  Better answer to the OP is to use `strict: false` as [this answer says.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389168/404699)

Answer (score 18):

Hey Chris, take a look at [Mongous](https://github.com/amark/mongous). I was having the same issue with mongoose, as my Schemas change extremely frequently right now in development. Mongous allowed me to have the simplicity of Mongoose, while being able to loosely define and change my 'schemas'. I chose to simply build out standard JavaScript objects and store them in the database like so

```
function User(user){
  this.name = user.name
, this.age = user.age
}

app.post('save/user', function(req,res,next){
  var u = new User(req.body)
  db('mydb.users').save(u)
  res.send(200)
  // that's it! You've saved a user
});
```

Far more simple than Mongoose, although I do believe you miss out on some cool middleware stuff like "pre". I didn't need any of that though. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Do you know how to handle errors in **mongous** by chance? This is somewhat missing in the docs.

Comment: I don't see this as the real answer to the question though, @kwhitley has the appropriate answer concerning Mongoose.

Comment: I would have to agree. I'm not sure, though, that Schema.types.mixed was available at the time of OP asking this question

Comment: OP here, I'm inclined to agree with you, however, the answer came a year after I'd already accepted this one.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the details description: [https://www.meanstack.site/2020/01/save-data-to-mongodb-without-defining.html][1]

```
    const express = require('express')()
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema

    express.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        // strict false will allow you to save document which is coming from the req.body
        const testCollectionSchema = new Schema({}, { strict: false })
        const TestCollection = mongoose.model('test_collection', testCollectionSchema)
        let body = req.body
        const testCollectionData = new TestCollection(body)
        await testCollectionData.save()
        return res.send({
            "msg": "Data Saved Successfully"
        })
    })


  [1]: https://www.meanstack.site/2020/01/save-data-to-mongodb-without-defining.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `{strict: false }` in scheme model and `{validateBeforeSave: false }` in save event

```
let MyScheme = new Schema(
    { <optional - basic fields if you want> ...},
    {strict: false }
)
let doc = new MyScheme(req.body)
doc.save({validateBeforeSave: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mongoose.connection.collection`

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const collection = mongoose.connection.collection('user')

// use it like a mongodb collection
await collection.updateOne({ name: "name" }, { $set: { name: "new_name" } })
```

See [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.collection())

Answer (score 0):

Note: The `{ strict: false }` parameter  will work for both create and update.

Answer (score -14):

Its not possible anymore.

You can use Mongoose with the collections that have schema and the node driver or another mongo module for those schemaless ones.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongoose-orm/Bj9KTjI0NAQ/qSojYmoDwDYJ