# Why is Mongoose replacing key/value pair in an object with _id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am creating my first backend project with Node.js, Express.js and Mongoose. I have a user, with a list of stocks objects `[{symbol: amount}]`.
When the user wants to buy a stock, they send a POST request with stock, an amount, and a verb in this case 'buy'. In the Post, I take the stock and amount from the request body and add it to the User's stock list.

A request with

```
{stock: 'F', amount: '2', verb: 'buy'}
```

should add

```
{'F': '2'}
```

to the user's stocks. The problem is when I create and push the stock with

```
stockObject[stock] = amount;
user.stocks.push(stockObject);
```

`user.stocks` becomes `[{ _id: 54be8739dd63f94c0e000004 }]` instead of `[{'F': '2'}]`, but when I make

```
stockObject={'symbol':stock, 'amount': amount}
```

and push that I will get

```
[{'symbol': 'F', 'amount': '2', _id: 54be8739dd63f94c0e000004}]
```

Why will Mongoose replace my data in the first case, but keep it in the second?

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    stocks: [{
        symbol: String,
        amount: Number
    }]
});

router.route('/user/:user_id/action')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        User.findOne({
            id: req.params.user_id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            var stock = req.body.stock;
            var amount = req.body.amount;
            var stockObject = {};
            if (req.body.verb === 'buy') {
                stockObject[stock] = amount;
            }
            user.stocks.push(stockObject);
            user.save(function(err) {
                res.json({
                    stocks: user.stocks
                });
            });

        });
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the first object you're trying to save:

```
console.log(stockObject);
// { 'F': '2' }
```

Doesn't match the `Schema` you've defined for it:

```
{
    symbol: String,
    amount: Number
}
```

Mongoose normalizes objects it saves based on the `Schema`, removing excess properties like `'F'` when it's expecting only `'symbol'` and `'amount'`.

```
if(req.body.verb === 'buy') {
    stockObject.symbol = stock;
    stockObject.amount = amount;
}
```

---

To get the output as `[{"F": "2"}]`, you could [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the collection before sending it to the client:

```
res.json({
    stocks: user.stocks.map(function (stock) {
        // in ES6
        // return { [stock.symbol]: stock.amount };

        var out = {};
        out[stock.symbol] = stock.amount;
        return out;
    });
});
```

Or, use the `Mixed` type, as mentioned in "[How do you use Mongoose without defining a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema)," that would allow you to store `{ 'F': '2' }`.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    stocks: [{
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }]
});
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So is there a way to specify the Key/Value pair in the schema, or should I be tracking each stock individually by its mongoose _id instead of trying to do user.stocks[stockSymbol]?