# Dynamic Schema in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN stack. 
In my application User performs a calculation operation ,
I am using mongodb map reduce  and  writing the  output to a collection in DB (say calculated_result)so that user can see the result later,
Hence I have created a dynamic MR output collection  named Calculated_result_userID.

Now the problem is "How can i defined a dynamic schema for this Collection"
I am using **MONGOOSE**

Eg.

```
var variableCollectionName = "calculated_result_"+userId;
    mongoose.model(variableCollectionName, mySchema);
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: `new Schema({},{ "strict": false})`. It's in the documenation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use Mongoose without defining a schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema)

Comment: No i mean Fields are same for my other collections, Only Collection name differs

Comment: Well since mapReduce output is always `{ "_id": '', "value": {} }` then I hope you don't have that. You cannot change the mapReduce output.

Comment: I have updated my Question please check once. Every user must have a collection ,like "collection_12","collection_18" etc