# MongoDB - various document types in one collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB is schemaless, which means a collection (table in relational DB) can contain documents (rows) of different structure - having different fields, for instance.

I'm new to Mongo, so I decided to use Mongoose which should make things a bit easier. Reading the [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

> Defining your schema
>
> Everything in Mongoose starts with a Schema. Each schema maps to a
>   MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that
>   collection.

Notice at the last sentence. Doesn't it conflict with the schemaless philosophy of MongoDB? Or maybe it's that in 99% of cases, I want a collection of documents of the same structure, so in the introductory guide only that scenario is discussed? Does Mongoose even allow me to create schemaless collection?

Comment: This may help you...
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema

Comment: "Schema-less" isn't an encouragement, it's an allowance. It's not suggesting you use poor design, it's allowing you to use it how you want and for what you want.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not require a schema, but that confuses a lot of people from a standard SQL background so Mongoose is aimed at trying to bridge the gap between SQL and NoSQL. If you want to maintain a collection with different document types, than by all means do not use Mongoose.

If you're okay with the schemaless nature of MongoDB there is no reason to add additional abstractions and overhead to MongoDB which is what Mongoose surely applies.

Answer (score 2):

NoSQL doesn't mean no schema. It means, the database doesn't control schema. For instance, with MongoDB, you can look hard to find anything that determines a field in a document is a string, or a number or a date. The database doesn't care. You could store a number in a field in one document and in another document in the same collection, and in the same field, you could store a string. But, from a coding perspective, that can become quite hairy and would be bad practice. This is why you still have to define data types. So, you still need a schema of sorts and why Mongoose offers and, in fact, enforces this functionality.

Going a conceptual level higher now, the major concept of NoSQL is to put schema inside your code and not in some file of SQL commands i.e. not telling the DB what to expect in terms of data types and schema to be controlled by the database. So, instead of needing to have migration files/paths and versioning on database schema, you just have your code. ORMs, for example, try to bridge this issue too, where they often have automated migration systems.

ORMs also try to avoid the [Object Relational Impedance Mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) problem, which MongoDB avoids completely. Well, it doesn't have relationships per se, so the problem is avoided out of necessity.

Getting back to schema, with MongoDB and Mongoose, if you or one of your team make a change to the schema in the code, all your other team members need to do to get the database to work with it is pull in that new code. Voila, the schema is up-to-date and will work. No need to also pull in a copy of the newer migration file (to determine the new schema of the DB) to then have to run it on a (copy of the) db to update it too, just to continue programming. There is no need to make changes in schema in multiple places.

So, in the end, if you can imagine your schema is always in your code (only), making changes to an application with a database persisting state like MongoDB is a good bit simpler and even safer. (Safer, because code and schema can't get out of sync, as it's the one and the same.)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Mongoose is to use a Schema, there are other database drivers you can use to take advantage of MongoDBs Schemaless nature such as [Mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin).

If you want to utilize the Mongoose's Schema Design and make an exeception you can use: [Mongoose Strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict).

According to the docs:

> The **strict option**, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.