# Mongoose — Create new property with $sum using aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to add a new field in all documents that contain the sum of an array of numbers.

Here is the Schema (removed irrelevant fields for brevity):

```
 var PollSchema = new Schema(
  {
    votes: [Number]
  }
 );
```

I establish the model:

```
PollModel = mongoose.model('Poll', PollSchema);
```

And I use aggregation to create a new field that contains the sum of the votes array.

```
PollModel.aggregate([
 {
  $project: {
    totalVotes: { $sum: "$votes"}
  }
 }
]);
```

When I startup my server, I get no errors; however, the `totalVotes` field hasn't been created.  I used [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-project-stage) documentation to help me.  It similarly uses the `$sum` operator and I did it exactly like the documentation illustrates, but no results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema

Comment: @Vishnu I have schema defined though?

Comment: You cannot get the fields that are not defined in the model. That is the problem.

Comment: @Vishnu The results from the aggregation framework are not contrained to the schema on the model but can be anything. So that's not the problem, but rather that you cannot apply `$sum` within `$project`, nor directly on an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not work as you think it does because "votes" is actually an array of values to start with, and then secondly because [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is an [accumulator operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) for usage in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage only.

So in order for you to get the total of the array as another property, first you must [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array and then `$group` together on the document key to `$sum` the total of the elements:

```js
PostModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$unwind": "$votes" },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "anotherField": { "$first": "$anotherField" },
            "totalVotes": { "$sum": "$votes" }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
);
```

Also noting here another accumulator in `$first` would be necessary for each additional field you want in results as `$group` and `$project` only return the fields you ask for.

Generally though this is better to keep as a property within each document for performance reasons, as it's faster than using aggregate. So to do this just increment a total each time you [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to an array by also using [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/):

```js
PostModel.update(
    { "_id": id },
    {
        "$push": { "votes": 5 },
        "$inc": { "totalVotes": 5 }
    },
    function(err,numAffected) {

    }
);
```

In that way the "totalVotes" field is always ready to use without the overhead of needing to deconstruct the array and sum the values for each document.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDb aggregation doesn't save its result into database. You just get the result of aggregation inline within a callback.
So after aggregation you would need to do multi update to your database:

```
PollModel.aggregate([
{
    $project: { totalVotes: { $sum: "$votes"} }
}]).exec( function(err, docs){
        // bulk is used for updating all records within a single query
        var bulk = PollModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

        // add all update operations to bulk
        docs.forEach(function(doc){
            bulk.find({_id: doc._id}).update({$set: {totalVotes: doc.totalVotes}});
        });

        // execute all bulk operations
        bulk.execute(function(err) {
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: I think this isn't working because I'm using Mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `totalVotes` in your schema. Just try the below code.

```
var PollSchema = new Schema(
  {
    votes: [Number],
    totalVotes: Number
  }
 );

PollModel.aggregate([
 {
  $project: {
    totalVotes: { $sum: "$votes"}
  }
 }
]);
```

or

```
resultData.toJSON();
```

Comment: I tried it, and the field shows up in the documents, but the value is just an empty array

Comment: @Matthew Just try the updated code. `totalVotes` should be an Number, not an array :P.

Answer (score 0):

@Blakes Seven and @Volodymyr Synytskyi helped me arrive to my solution!  I also found [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) documentation particularly helpful.

```
PollModel.aggregate(
[
    { '$unwind': '$votes' },
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'totalVotes': { '$sum': '$votes' }
    }}
],
function(err,results) {
    // console.log(results);
    results.forEach(function(result){
        var conditions = { _id: result._id }, 
            update = { totalVotes: result.totalVotes }, 
            options = { multi: true };

        PollModel.update(conditions, update, options, callback);

        function callback (err, numAffected) {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            } else {
                // console.log(numAffected);
            }
        }
    });
}
);
```