# how to read all the field from object return from "findOne" in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongose for creating my model.
my model is

```
var UserPoll = new Schema({
   poll_string: String
}, {
   strict: false
});
```

now i am adding `no_of_vote` field specified by user at run time and writing into DB. Everything is working fine.

While reading from db i am using

```
UserPoll.findOne({
     poll_string: poll_string
}, {
     _id: false
},  function(err, userpoll){
        if (err) {
            // handling error
        } else {
            console.log("" + userPoll);
        }
    }
});
```

When I print `userpoll`, it prints all the field but when i try to access the field which was added dynamically, it says undefined.

```
// userpoll output -  
{ 
    poll_string: 'favourite dish?',
    No_of_vote1: 15,
    No_of_vote2: 10,
    No_of_vote3: 1,
    No_of_vote4: 0,
    No_of_vote5: 0,
    __v: 0 
}
```

where `No_of_vote(1,2,3,4,5)` is total no of count of votes for option (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
I am not able to access No_of_vote field.

Please help..

I recently started learning Nodejs as well mongodb.

Comment: Can you clarify Filed or field?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema

Comment: You might want to save the return value to a variable and access those fields using the variable. I'd also suggest you start using `Promises` instead of callbacks.

Comment: sorry , it is field

Comment: Are you trying to access the mongoose returned object directly? If so, try converting toObject or the lean() option on your query.