# Storing objects of variable structure in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm moving my first steps with mongodb and node.js and I have some doubts about mongoose and storing received data.

I'm trying to make a REST API with an endpoint for submitting (POST) "stuff" in json format.
I would store this "stuff" in mongodb but I've no precise schema: submitted data are all similar and related but some of them may differ by some fields.

For example, I could receive:

object_1

```
{
  field1: value1
  field2: value2
}
```

object_2

```
{
  field1: value1
  field3: value3
}
```

They are somehow similar, both of them represent the same object type, they just have some fields missing (like null or whatever).

Reading some docs and tutorials, I saw that mongoose require a "schema", like

```
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
   foo: String
   bar: String
});
```

What if I don't have a fixed schema? Can I store 'object_1' and 'object_2' in the same collection (since they are related) without using a schema?

Thanks!

EDIT:

To be clear, submited json come from a survey, for example:

```
{
  // standard/default fields
  id: 2,
  date: 'timestamp',
  surveyId: 13,
  ...
  // here starts non-standard fields list
}
```

Each survey has a number of fields but not every field is mandatory, sometimes a fields could be left blank (or null) and it is not included in json body at all. In one submission I may have {field1, field2, field3}, in the next one {field1, field3, field4, field5} and so on...

Some of them are standard like id, datetime and some others. I can declare them in my schema, but what about the others?

I hope it's clear!

Thanks!

Comment: It's generally not recommended to use dynamic keys in objects since you won't easily be able to retrieve them afterwards. Could you give us a more concrete example of why you want to do this?

Comment: Sure, they are basically data coming from some survey, each submission could have some fields and another one could have other fields. Each one has some standard fields (like id, survey_id, datetime and some others). I'm editing the first post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use Mongoose without defining a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a schema with all possible keys, but not require all of them to be filled. That way you can reuse the schema for both objects, where some keys will have values and others will be undefined.

```
var survey = mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
  date: String,
  surveyId: Number,
  customfield1: String,
  customfield2: String
});
```

When you post object_1 you would get something like

```
{
  id: 1,
  date: 'timestamp',
  surveyId: 1,
  customfield1: 'value'
}
```

whereas with object_2 you would get

```
{
  id: 2,
  date: 'timestamp',
  surveyId: 2,
  customfield*2*: 'value'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This could be an option. Problem is: there are a lot possible keys and they may be changed over time. I should update after every single edit or create a new schema...