# Is it possible to populate without schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have an application that uses mongo's oplog to follow insert, update and delete operations. I would like to get to full document through mongoose (populated), everytime one of the operations occur (findById with the id I get from the oplog), but I do not have the Schemas as there are defined in another application.

Do you think it is possible to get the full document without cloning the other application and registering each schemas for each model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use Mongoose without defining a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema)

Comment: I actually can retrieve the documents values, I just can't populate the other documents it references.