# Promise functionality with Node and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I'm using Mongous in a Node project to manipulate a MongoDB database, necessarily without a schema, having about 6000 documents. My goal is to retrieve all documents from a collection and process each of them synchronously.

```
const mongous = require('mongous').Mongous;

getDocuments()
    .then((documents) => processDocuments(documents));

function getDocuments() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongous('myDatabase.someCollection').find({}, reply => {
            console.log(`Returning ${reply.numberReturned} documents`);
            resolve(reply);
        });
    });
}

function processDocuments(documents) {
    let beginning = documents.startingFrom;
    let end = beginning + documents.numberReturned;
    console.log(`Processing documents from ${beginning} to ${end}\n`);
    // Process...
}
```

However, I am running into problems using [Mongous](https://github.com/amark/mongous)'s `find` function. What I expect is for the function to return all of the documents in one reply. However, it seems to have some kind of batch limit, because it doesn't return more than 500 documents at once.

Output:

```
Returning 101 documents
Processing documents from 0 to 101

Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 500 documents
Returning 495 documents
```

Why doesn't `then((documents => processDocuments(documents))` work for the subsequent resolved replies?

Comment: A promise will resolve or reject only once

Comment: For posterity: if you find yourself using Mongous as an easy way to manage your schema-less database, there are [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389168/9154756) ways.

Comment: Note that mongous hasn't been updated since 2015. You might want to update to [officially supported MongoDB node driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) instead.