# Generate models from database that already exist with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and MongoDB and I always create the schema and set the properties and then create the database collection with `mongoose.model("Model name", "schemaName")` but now I want to use the prepared database in the atlas and I am wondering how I can generate my models from the database?

Comment: I think you don't need to. The first time you are connecting to the Atlas db, mongoose it will create collections and indexes as defined in the schema.

Comment: How can I use mongoose methods for example model.find() I have no model to use

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you correctly. You still are using your node.js / javascript code, aren't you? The only thing you need to only change is the connection string to use the Atlas server instead of your local server.

Comment: Yes, I have access to my database in Atlas but I want to do CRUD operations. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. Well, Mongo does not have an understanding of schema’s, so you cannot extract that. But you can use Mongoose without a schema. See the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370846/how-do-you-use-mongoose-without-defining-a-schema

Comment: You could also try to connect to mongodb with the mongodb drivers instead of mongoose. Mongoose is not ment to use it without a schema. Maybe you can write the schema based on the data you see in the database?

Comment: Yes, I know what you are saying and I used your reference link. thank you so much